# SwiftUI list of different UI elements - fail

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to present a list, of witch the first item is a `NavigationLink`, because its configuration needs some extra options to be defined. All other operations can be run w/o special parameters.

(Code stripped down a bit):

```
let operations = ["start", "stop", "set_marker", "save_map", "get_status"]    

NavigationView {
    VStack {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Header")) {
                List(operations, id: \.self) { operation in
                    if operation == "start" {
                        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(operation: operation)) {
                            Text(operation.uppercased())
                        }
                    } else {
                        Button(action: {
                            switch operation {
                            case "stop":
                                break
                            default:
                                break
                            }            
                        }) {
                            Text(operation.uppercased()).foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The thing compiles fine and displays fine too. At runtime I can click all "plain buttons" and it works. For the "start" entry I can open the second window just once. After return the "start" button does not react anymore. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Disregard. Seems to be an issue on emulator and in preview only.

Comment: not exactly, it is known bug and it works the same way on real device

Comment: I didn't see the problem on a real device, but my approach is different now.